# Where to get accurate cpu temprature readings?

Tags: cpu, cooling, heatsink

I am trying to read my cpu temprature under full load (After overclocking by 0.3 ghz). For this I have used CPUID HWmonitor, Core Temp and SpeedFan. CoreTemp and HWmonitor seams to show good tempratures of 46c under full load. However, Speedfan is showing a worrying "Temp1" and "Temp2" at over 50 and over 70c each. What exactly is Temp1 and 2, and if it is the cpu, why is the reading so different from the ones of HWmonitor and CoreTemp? My bios in turn is showing a high idle temp of 45c slowly climbing to 50c during the time spent in bios, however, i have heard that the cpu is not really idle in that condition, and that this is "normal", but not even HWmointor and CoreTemp is showing 50c under full load...

In speedfan, Temp1 ,2 and 3 is listed as: Chip: F71889A

... SEE PICTURE BELLOW ...
[image]

Comment: Don't they all agree on the core temp? What kind of mobo do you have? Maybe it has sensors (Temp 1, 2 & 3) to help it out with controlling fanspeeds

Comment: @Louis Yes, but does Core temp = CPU temp? I always assumed  CPU 0 was accurate and that Core Temp = CPU temp, but does it? and if so, what is the Temp 1, Temp 2 and Temp 3 readings coming from? The same tempratures shows in HWmonitor under "Tempratures" as TMPIN0 and TMPIN1... I have a MSI 970A-G46 motherboard...

Comment: Yep, core temp is [directly from the CPU](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/howitworks.html). I don't know where the other sensors are. I guess you could break out a magnifying glass and look for chips with that F71889A marking.

Comment: You could also try blowing on certain parts of the board and seeing which temp drops :) But it would make sense if the sensors were by their respective fans.

Comment: @Louis So it is safe to ignore the 53c and 77c readings? or at least, they are not the cpu?  they do seam to be effected by cpu temprature as they increase/decrease along with core temprature... I am asking because i recently switched froms stock fans to a hyper 212 evo, and got very good idle temps of 18c and load temp of 37c, i then decided to overclock from 4.ghz to 4.3ghz... Still getting good temps of 26c idle and 46-47c under load, but i got worried i might have been looking at the wrong readings... hehe

Answer (score 0):

Some CPUs have multiple thermocouples. this may be where you are getting multiple temperature readings. I would try to find out more info on your specific processor by way of multiple thermocouples and how they may be averaged in software.

Comment: Thanks. Could the high readings be my ram? i do have 3 ram chips...

Answer (score -1):

This link provides a C# program that taps into a free "OpenHardwareMonitor" dll.

https://www.hackster.io/haoming-weng/get-cpu-temperature-using-open-hardware-monitor-in-c-1a3338?utm_source=hackster&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_projects